# Feminine form for "in the style of"

Tags: translation, gender

When we want to say "in the style of" in Italian, why do we use the feminine form? I mean, in such expressions as "vitello alla parmigianA" or the film "Divorzio all'ItalianA"? Style, in Italian, lo stile, is masculine. Maybe we could say the translation really is in the **fashion** (moda) of?

Comment: Interesting, but what's the question?

Comment: @Gio: I think that the question is: why do we use the feminine form in such expressions?

Comment: I think it's because it stands for "alla maniera". For instance, "alla parmigiana" = "alla maniera parmigiana", "all'italiana" = "alla maniera italiana".

Comment: For instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_variata_alla_maniera_italiana

Comment: @Charo I think you could write it as an answer

Comment: Just to clarify: *moda* is almost never used in this sense. Its main use is more or less “fashion”, but only in the sense of “popular style of clothing, behaviour etc.”; a secondary meaning is the statistical one, as “mode” in the sense of “the value that occurs most frequently in a given set of data”. The use of *moda* in the sense of “manner of doing something” is now obsolete by some century.

Comment: Yes, the meaning is "alla maniera di". It's like to say italian wise etc.

Answer (score 7):

We use the feminine form of adjectives in such expressions because they stand for "alla maniera". In your examples,

> - "alla parmigiana" = "alla maniera parmigiana",
> - "all'italiana" = "alla maniera italiana".

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_variata_alla_maniera_italiana) you can find an example of use of the expression "alla maniera italiana".

Comment: "Maniera" is not "style"!!!